# explain why ${\left(\frac{{1}}{{2}}\right)}^{\infty}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, nonstandard-analysis

[Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%5Eoo) shows 
${\left(\frac{{1}}{{2}}\right)}^{\infty}=0$, anyone can explain why ?

I know we can get $\lim\limits_{{{x}\to\infty}}{\left(\frac{{1}}{{2}}\right)}^{{x}}={0}$ by taking limit , does ${\left(\frac{{1}}{{2}}\right)}^{\infty}$ is just an abbreviated expression of $\lim\limits_{{{x}\to\infty}}{\left(\frac{{1}}{{2}}\right)}^{{x}}$

P.S. $\infty = +\infty$ here.

Comment: Yes. (words to fill the comment)

Comment: As long as you agree that $\infty = +\infty$. I personally don't, and in calculus I usually teach that $\infty$ means nothing. But Mathematica agrees with this shorthand.

Comment: Well exactly infinity would not be defined, because it's a concept not a number. However, the notation that $lim_{x\to \infty}$ implies that $x$ is approaching infinity. If you directly say that it's an abbreviation, it won't be a good idea. It's the limit as $x$ approaches it.

Comment: @Siminore yes, $\infty = +\infty$ here. I think infinity could be used as a number to measure quantities that finite number , like real number, could not measure, infinity is greater than any assignable quantity or countable number, while “x tends to infinity”(x→∞) is actually an unending procedure.

Comment: @Mann I think infinity could be used as a number to measure quantities that finite number , like real number, could not measure, infinity is greater than any assignable quantity or countable number, while “x tends to infinity”(x→∞) is actually an unending procedure.

Comment: Yes, you're correct in your understanding. Mathematically speaking, $(1/2)^{\infty}$ is not defined since $\infty\notin\Bbb{C}$ but maybe they're using that notation to denote the limiting value.

Comment: Look up "extended real numbers".

Comment: @Mann I think you should not say " x is approaching infinity" but "x becomes infinite" because infinity is neither a number nor a place. You'd better read this http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/infinity.htm

Answer (score 3):

$(1/2)^2=1/4$ and $(1/2)^{10}=1/1024$ and then $(1/2)^{20}=1/1048576$. As the power gets larger, the denominator approaches infinity. This makes the value of the fraction tend to zero.

This might help. [image]

Comment: I have already known what you said here, but you seems doesn't answered my question

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a *definition* from Wolfram Alpha. As you see [here!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%5Eoo%20%3D%3D%20lim_%28x%20-%3E%20inf%29%20%281%2F2%29%5Ex)
If you type in $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\infty == \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x $, then Wolfram Alpha give you the result: **True**.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is probably $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} {\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{x}$$

A limit can be defined with epsilon and delta. I.e. can we find any number $\delta$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ which the expression is close enough to.

A variant of this: We can take the binary number $2^{-i}$ for an integer $i$ which is bounded below by 0, because positive numbers are closed under multiplication. We see that we can make the expression smaller than any such binary number, by just making $x$ large enough, say $x = i + 1$. But the binary number system is good enough to express any positive number if enough digits are allowed. Therefore the limit must be 0.